# mongodb bulkWrite with nodejs/typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

I want to do bulk update on mongodb with the following code.

```
async function main() {
  try {
    const operations:any = []
    users.forEach(async user => {
      const custId = decrypt(user.id)
      const customer = await CustomerModel.findOne({ custId: custId })
      if (customer) {
        let { setting, ...objData } = customer
        setting = {
          ...setting,
          ...{
            description: user.description
          }
        }
        const doc = {
            updateOne: {
              filter: { custId: custId },
              update: { location: 'USA', ...setting }
            }
        }
          operations.push(doc)
      }
    })
    console.log(operations)
    const res = await CustomerModel.bulkWrite(operations)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
main()
```

When I execute the code above, no document is updated. I think it's because operations.push section was called after 'CustomerModel.bulkWrite' is executed. When I print some debugging lines, i noticed that 'operations.push' was called after  'CustomerModel.bulkWrite(operations)' line.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i noticed that 'operations.push' was called after 'CustomerModel.bulkWrite(operations)' line.

This sounds like a classic async issue indeed. In that case, you are troubled by the `.forEach()` method, which cannot await. Instead, you could use an old school `for...of` loop, or `.map()` your Promises and await all of them:

```
// Old school for...of loop,
// makes waiting at each step easy
for (const user of users) {
  // ...
  const customer = await CustomerModel.findOne({ custId: custId })
  // ...
  operations.push(doc);
}

// Await all Promises,
// more parallelism while still waiting for
// all to complete before moving on
await Promise.all(
  users.map(async user => {
    // ...
  })
);

// Variant where you explicitly build
// your `operations` array from the Promises
const operations = await Promise.all(
  users.map(async user => {
    // ...
    return doc;
  })
);
```